# Running into factor issue with R function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a data.frame named `gwas.data`

```
        SNP A1 A2         EFF     FRQ
2353 rs10001803  A  G -0.06620391 0.06860
2307 rs10002573  T  C -0.03969763 0.78100
504  rs10003143  A  C  0.03829721 0.53170
1802  rs1001022  T  C  0.08159842 0.96174
461  rs10011564  T  C  0.04930432 0.27840
2331 rs10013187  A  C -0.03600030 0.54490
```

I have a second frame named `correct.orientation`:

```
      SNP   CLST A1 A2  FRQ IMP       POS CHR BVAL
54445  rs10001803 Brahui  G  A 1.00   1 157121506   4  898
49713  rs10002573 Brahui  C  T 0.26   0  31120097   4  983
52885  rs10003143 Brahui  A  C 0.42   0 114272159   4  918
193805  rs1001022 Brahui  T  C 0.98   0  24733488  22  970
48257  rs10011564 Brahui  T  C 0.10   1  18734768   4  863
52313  rs10013187 Brahui  C  A 0.34   1 103040573   4  908
```

I am trying to have the columns of A1 and A2 match up between the two files. If the columns of `gwas.data` are flipped from the `correct.orientation` then I want to flip them to the correct orientation. If I flip them, I also want to change the sign of the `EFF` column and take (1-FRQ) for the `FRQ` column. Here is the code I am currently trying to use to do this:

```
gwas.data <- MatchAlleles ( gwas.data , assoc.loci.freqs)    
MatchAlleles <- function ( gwas.data , assoc.loci.freqs ) {

            if ( nrow ( gwas.data ) != nrow ( correct.orientation ) ) {
                    stop ( "GWAS dataset and Orientation Matching dataset contain differing numbers of SNPs" )
            }

            flip <- gwas.data$A1 == correct.orientation$A2 & gwas.data$A2 == correct.orientation$A1
            dont.flip <- gwas.data$A1 == correct.orientation$A1 & gwas.data$A2 == correct.orientation$A2
            for ( i in 1 : nrow ( gwas.data ) ) {
                    if ( flip [ i ] ) {
                            gwas.data$A1 [ i ] <- correct.orientation$A1 [ i ]
                            gwas.data$A2 [ i ] <- correct.orientation$A2 [ i ]
                            gwas.data$EFF [ i ] <- - gwas.data$EFF [ i ]
                            gwas.data$FRQ [ i ] <- 1 - gwas.data$FRQ [ i ]
                    } else if ( dont.flip [ i ] ) {
                            #do nothing
                    } else {
                            stop ( "Strand Issue")
                    }
            }
    return ( gwas.data )
    }
```

The `assoc.loci.freqs` term is irrelevant and included in the original code but is higher up in the function and doesn't effect this. When I try to use this code I get the error: `Error in Ops.factor(gwas.data$A1, correct.orientation$A2) : 
  level sets of factors are different` What could be causing this?

Comment: Have tried just converting the factors to characters? Or reading the files in such that you set `as.is = TRUE` to avoid creating factors?

Comment: Are the two dataframes the same length? (number of rows)

Comment: I'm an idiot...yes they are same length, but @Dayne fixed it

Comment: IMO, it's generally not a good idea to use factors unless you are doing it explicitly and for good reason. For example, `data.table` package defaults to characters when reading data.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that a certain nucleotide is in `gwas.data$A1` but not `correct.orientation$A2`? Using the example given above, the factor levels from `A1` are `A` and `T`, while the factor levels from `A2` are `A`, `T`, and `C`.

The suggestions in @dayne's comments should circumvent this problem.